# How to be focused while reading a paper?

Tags: research-process

I am currently a researcher(PhD student). I work on this which needs long hours of sitting with concentration and quite some time to get a result or a paper.

Reading a paper takes time. Let us say I want to read a paper. I usually try to sit down a start reading it then try to write the things in my notebook. During this phase I can't able to focus on the content. I am getting distracted by many things email, messages etc. I don't this is the case with everyone in academia or not. Due to this distraction I am very slow in focusing on the things in which I want to pay attention. I notices that I can't focus more that 10 minutes on one thing in such situation.

The problem I am facing is distraction from the many sources and this distraction is making hard to understand the proofs/theorems I want to understand.

I have also observed on thing if I am understanding the content then it is unlikely I will open a new tab/ window in my computer.

In my past I have tried to block the sites/fb etc email account also but what happened that I missed some deadlines due to that. I have observed I can pay more attention once I block all the mentioned websites but that is also probelmatic.

**Question :** How to be focused while reading a paper? Are there any techniques/ some methods to tackle this problem?

Comment: "_getting distracted by many things email, messages_" Did you try turning off your mobile phone and e-mail while reading the paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print out the paper. Sit away from your computer, phone, and other distracting elements. Close the office door, perhaps. Make annotations on the paper as you go.

When finished, transfer a *summary* to your notebook using the annotations you made on the paper.

If you don't want to mark up the paper, use index cards for your notations. Put only one thought on each card or only closely related thoughts. Then use those to create a summary for your notebook. If you put the name, etc., of the paper on the cards they can be easily carried for review if you need to reinforce your memory about the paper. This might be easier than carrying your notebook(s).

---

Note that using a two step process to get things into your notebooks is also a reinforcement mechanism that helps you learn what you are reading, not just process it. Review of your notations is additional reinforcement. It is a mistake to bypass this for most people.

Comment: (+1) *Print out the paper. Sit away from ...* --- I was formulating in my mind a reply that began with exactly this as I was scanning through the comments and the (at this time, only) other answer, then I saw what you wrote.